# Is it possible to set property object variable in another class in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have a property in my UIView class, something like that:

myView.h

```
@ interface MyView: UIView {

id refView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id refView;
```

MyView.m

```
@synthesis refView;
```

Then in another class can I set the refView property of MyView something like that:

MyViewController.h

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController {

UIView *myView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
```

then in MyViewController.m:

```
[self.myView setRefView:someValue];
```

When I do that I get this warning: UIView may not response to '-setRefView:' ...

So, is the above way is right or what's the right way to do it. Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the refView property to MyView class, not UIView, that's why the compiler complains. If you initialize myView with a MyView instance, this will work, even if there's a warning.

To prevent the compiler from complaining, change

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController {

UIView *myView;

}
```

to

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController {

MyView *myView;

}
```